# Differential equations, money

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The increase of money in your account is proportional to the amount of money that you already have in your account.  You deposit \$1 per hour into your account.  Model this using differential equations.

My attempt:

$y' = ky + a$ where $a$ is the portion of that \$1/h. But the question is, how am I supposed to find out the correct portion of that \$1/h.  That is,how do I find $a$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try thinking about the problem in the case where the interest rate is zero. You get $y'=a$, which has solution $y=at+c$. If time is expressed in hours, then you want $a=1$. (note: make sure you express $k$ using the same units.)

Of course, the typical undergraduate approach isn't a completely honest representation of the situation. If you're depositing one dollar an hour you won't get a nice continuous curve, you'll have a discontinuous one that jumps every hour.

Answer (score 0):

You're making it too complicated; just put $a=1$